# Java JTextPane Save

Tags: java, swing, save, jtextpane

i was trying to do some simple text formatting using JEditorPane but then as knowledge grew i found JTextPane easier to implement and more robust.

my query is how do i save the formatted text in JTextPane to file? it should be RTF or HTML or other.. as this file is not opened by the application again.

it is a chat history text file with formatted text.

thank you.

Comment: Cross posted in at least 3 other forums: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5437282&tstart=0. Apparently the answer given here is too complicated, yet I see no follow up question.

Comment: thats because i havent made much progress with regards to understanding the solution contributed.

Comment: @camickr: hopefully no bad feelings. it took too much chaos to get to the answer this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have write method for HTML and RTF from StyledEditorKit. See [HTMLEditorKit.write](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html#write%28java.io.Writer,%20javax.swing.text.Document,%20int,%20int%29) and RTFEditorKit

Comment: thanks it took really long this time around to understand the issue but glad it worked out. now have a working demo. :)