# Saving jTextPane style to a document (xml)

Tags: java, swing, formatting, styles, jtextpane

I making a text editor that the user can apply formatting such as bold and underline. I was able to do this using `jTextPane` and `StyleConstants`, however i don't know how to save the styling on the document such as `.docx` and `.doc`!!
all i know that i could use the following statement, but i have no idea how to make use of it !!

```
Element element = jTextPane.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
```

Please can you help me with this, thank you in advance^^

Comment: See ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723073/java-jtextpane-save)*** post

Answer (score 1):

You can read this http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial.html (section about reader and writer)

Or use the kit http://java-sl.com/docx_editor_kit.html as start point for your code. It's basic implementation for docx